# How to insert text inside a shape that i will draw in Java

Tags: java, text, shapes, graphics2d, rectangles

So i want to insert text inside a shape. This shape will be drawn by the user, e.g a rectangle. When the mouse is released, a pop-up message is sent "Enter name:". The user enters the name for the rectangle and then it appears directly inside the shape rectangle.

Can you please guide me to achieve this? What will be the right way to do this?
I already have my block of code where i draw the rectangle and it sends the pop-up message but i don't know how to put the "text inside the shape"

Here is the userinterface to draw the shapes.

```html
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Lesson49_1 extends JFrame {
    private int c;
    
    public int getC() {
    return c;
}
public void setC(int c) {
    this.c= this.c;
}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -140274271716086522L;

    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu File, Exit;
    JMenuItem New, Open;
    JComponent DrawingBoard;
    Font textFont;
    String text;
    Color textColor;
    {
        
        textColor = new Color(0x404000);
        
       text = "Hello, World!";
        
    }

    JButton  lineBut, ellipseBut, rectBut, strokeBut;

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    // Contains all of the rules for drawing

    Graphics2D graphSettings;

   
    // Going to be used to monitor what shape to draw next

    int currentAction = 1;
    

    // Transparency of the shape

    // Default stroke and fill colors

    Color strokeColor = Color.BLACK;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Lesson49_1();
    }
    
    
    
    
    public Lesson49_1() {
        // Define the defaults for the JFrame
        
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setTitle("ERD BUILDER");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // Add the menubar to the frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Define and add two drop down menu to the menubar
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu dbMenu = new JMenu("Database");
        JMenu ToolsMenu = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(dbMenu);
        menuBar.add(ToolsMenu);
        menuBar.add(HelpMenu);
        // Create and add simple menu item to one of the drop down menu
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New Project");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem UndoAction = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        JMenuItem RedoAction = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        JMenuItem clearAction = new JMenuItem("Clear");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exportAction = new JMenuItem("Export");
        JMenuItem printAction = new JMenuItem("Print");
        JMenuItem ConvertAction = new JMenuItem("Convert To Tables");
        JMenuItem ColorAction = new JMenuItem("Color Picker");
        JMenuItem ZoomAction = new JMenuItem("Zoom");
        JMenuItem EntityAction = new JMenuItem("Entity & Attributes");
        JMenuItem RelationshipAction = new JMenuItem("Relationship Attributes");
        JMenuItem HelpAction = new JMenuItem("Help");
        JMenuItem AboutAction = new JMenuItem("About");

        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exportAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(printAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);

        editMenu.add(UndoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(RedoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(clearAction);

        dbMenu.add(ConvertAction);

        ToolsMenu.add(ColorAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(ZoomAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(EntityAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(RelationshipAction);

        HelpMenu.add(HelpAction);
        HelpMenu.addSeparator();
        HelpMenu.add(AboutAction);
        
        
        exitAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               
        }}
        );
        
        
        
        
        
        
        ConvertAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
               //new ConvertForm().setVisible(true);
                
                
               
        }}
        );
        
        
        

        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                new Lesson49_1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
       
        JPanel FieldPanel = new JPanel();

        // Swing box that will hold all the buttons

        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        Box theBoxs = Box.createVerticalBox();

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeButtons by passing the
        // button icon.

        
        lineBut = makeMeButtons("./src/line.png", 2);
        ellipseBut = makeMeButtons("./src/ellipse.png", 3);
        rectBut = makeMeButtons("./src/rectangle.png", 4);

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeColorButton by passing the
        // button icon and true for stroke color or false for fill

        strokeBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/stroke.png", 5, true);


        // Add the fields to the boxs

        

        //theBox.add(brushBut);
        theBox.add(lineBut);
        theBox.add(ellipseBut);
        theBox.add(rectBut);
        theBox.add(strokeBut);
       
        buttonPanel.add(theBox);
        FieldPanel.add(theBoxs);
        

        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(FieldPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,480));        
        FieldPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,480));
        // Make the drawing area take up the rest of the frame

        // this.add(new DrawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final DrawingBoard drawPanel = new DrawingBoard();
        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        
        
        
        
        
        exportAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(),
                        drawPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                drawPanel.paint(g);
                g.dispose();

                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                File theDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Wenda/Desktop");
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
                FileNameExtensionFilter pngFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "PNG file (*.png)", "png");
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pngFilter);
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(pngFilter);

                int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(Lesson49_1.this);

                if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(image, "png",
                                fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image saved to "
                                + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Show the frame
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JButton makeMeButtons(String iconFile, final int actionNum) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

         theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentAction = actionNum;
            }
        });
        return theBut;
    }

    // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied and
    // whether a stroke or fill is to be defined

    public JButton makeMeColorButton(String iconFile, final int actionNum,
            final boolean stroke) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (stroke) {

                    // JColorChooser is a popup that lets you pick a color

                    strokeColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,
                            "Pick a Stroke", Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                                    }
            }
        });

        return theBut;
    }
    public class DrawingBoard extends JComponent {
        Font textFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431176095451940075L;

        // ArrayLists that contain each shape drawn along with
        // that shapes stroke and fill
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        
        Point drawStart, drawEnd;
        // Monitors events on the drawing area of the frame

        public DrawingBoard() {
                      

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (currentAction != 1) {

                        // When the mouse is pressed get x & y position

                        drawStart = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        drawEnd = drawStart;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    int counts =0;
                    if (currentAction != 1) {
                        Shape aShape = null;
                        
                        if (currentAction == 2) {
                            aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                            e.getX(), e.getY());
                            shapes.add(aShape);
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;
                            repaint();
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 3) {
                            aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                             e.getX(), e.getY());
                            shapes.add(aShape);
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;                                                        
                            repaint();
                            counts = counts+1;
                            count.add(counts);
                            int sizes = count.size();
                            System.out.println(sizes);
//                            new AttributeForm().setVisible(true);
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 4) {
                            //draw the rectangle
                            aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                            e.getX(), e.getY());
                            shapes.add(aShape);
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;
                            
                            
                            String text = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(DrawingBoard, "Enter name:");
                            while (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
                                    text = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(DrawingBoard, "You must enter a valid name!  Please try again:");
                                                                    
                            }
                             repaint();      
                                    


    

                          //new EntityForm().setVisible(true);
                        }

                        // Add shapes, fills and colors to there ArrayLists

                                              

                    }

                }
            });
            
              this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                for (Shape s : shapes) {

                    if (s.contains(me.getPoint())) {//check if mouse is clicked within shape

                        //we can either just print out the object class name
                        System.out.println("Clicked a "+s.getClass().getName());

                        //or check the shape class we are dealing with using instance of with nested if
                        if (s instanceof Rectangle2D) {
                            
                            //create table  
                            
                        } 
                         else if (s instanceof Ellipse2D) {
                            
                           
                             
                            
                            
                            
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });

            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                    // If this is a brush have shapes go on the screen quickly

                    if (currentAction == 1) {

                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();

                        Shape aShape = null;
                        shapes.add(aShape);

                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);

                        // Add the transparency value
                    }

                    // Get the final x & y position after the mouse is dragged

                    drawEnd = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            
            final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();
             final double size = Math.sqrt(width * height);
            // Class used to define the shapes to be drawn

            graphSettings = (Graphics2D) g;
            

            // Antialiasing cleans up the jagged lines and defines rendering
            // rules

            graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // Defines the line width of the stroke

            graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

            // Iterators created to cycle through strokes and fills
            Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
            for (Shape s : shapes) {
 
                // Grabs the next stroke from the color arraylist
                graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());

                graphSettings.draw(s);

            }

            // Guide shape used for drawing
            if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null) {
                // Makes the guide shape transparent

                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));

                // Make guide shape gray for professional look

                graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                Shape aShape = null;

                if (currentAction == 2) {
                    aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 3) {
                    aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 4) {
                    

                    // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                    aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);  
                    //Add text inside the rectangle
                    
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
        Font textFont = this.textFont.deriveFont((float) size * (1 / 12f));
        g.setFont(textFont);
        FontMetrics textMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        g.drawString(text, (width - textMetrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (textMetrics.getAscent() + (height - (textMetrics.getAscent() + textMetrics.getDescent())) / 2));
                    
                    
                    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                                int fontAscent = fm.getAscent();                                
                                int stringX = Math.min(drawStart.x, drawEnd.x);
                                int stringY = Math.min(drawStart.y, drawEnd.y) + fontAscent;
                                g.drawString(text, stringX,  stringY);

                }

                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
            }
        }

    
        private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            // Get the top left hand corner for the shape
            // Math.min returns the points closest to 0

            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

            // Gets the difference between the coordinates and

            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

           private Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

        private Line2D.Float drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

            return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
        
       public void drawString(String text,int stringX, int stringY){
        }
        
           }
    
    }
```

And the EntityForm is the form that gets the name of the rectangle. It's a simple form that says "Enter name:"

**"CODE EDITED(3)"**

Comment: What did you try yourself? Show some code.

Comment: @Blaatz0r    Please see the above edited code.

Comment: What part are you struggling with?  Getting the text from the form or drawing the text on the JComponent?

Comment: @daiscog Both. I want to get the text from the form and put in into the shape. Can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two problems:

1. How to get the text the user entered
2. How to draw the text in the rectangle

**Getting the Text**

Your EntityForm class should have some sort of accessor method to get either the text field itself or the value of the text field (i.e., the text the user entered).

I assume it also has an "Okay" button in it for the user to click once the text is entered?  So you'll need to first save a reference to the new EntityForm, then add an event handler to the "okay" button, before you set it to visible.

So, for example:

```
final EntityForm ef = new EntityForm();
ef.getOkayButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String text = ef.getTextInput().getText();
        // draw text code here...

    }
});
ef.setVisible(true);
```

The above is obviously just an example as I do not know the API of the EntityForm class, but it should be enough to get you going.  If you need a more specific answer, then you'll need to post the code for EntityForm, too.

However, an easier option than using the EntityForm class is to use the built-in [JOptionPane.showInputDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) method.  So instead of calling `new EntityForm()`, you can do this:

```
String text = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(drawingBoard, "Enter name:");
// Note that if the user presses "cancel" then text will be null.  Also, 
// user may not have entered any text and pressed "okay", so text will be
// an empty string.
if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
    text = "[unnamed]";
}
// Instead of substituting for an alternative string, you could show 
// an error message and ask the user for a name again until a valid
// name is supplied.e.g.:
/*
while (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
    text = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(drawingBoard, "You must enter a valid name!  Please try again:");
}
*/

// draw text code here...
```

**Drawing the Text**

One of the [Graphics2d#drawString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) methods is needed here.  Check the API docs for more details and options, but the gist of it is:

```
// get the size of the current font
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
int fontAscent = fm.getAscent();

// drawString co-ordinates specify the baseline of the text, so lets 
// tell it to draw at fontAscent pixels below the top of the rectangle.
// Note that the user might have started dragging from any corner of the 
// rectangle, so we need to determine which co-ordinates represent the 
// top-left most point of the rectangle by looking for the lowest value:
int stringX = Math.min(drawStart.x, drawEnd.x);
int stringY = Math.min(drawStart.y, drawEnd.y) + fontAscent;
// To add n pixles of padding between the rectangle edge and the string,
// just add n to the numbers passed in to the drawString() method here:
g.drawString(text, stringX  stringY);
```

Note that the above code makes no attempt to ensure the text fits inside the rectangle.  To do that, you'll need to use `fm.stringWidth(text)` and then decide whether you want to clip the drawn text, scale it, or reduce the font size until it fits (which it might never do).  All of that is a little beyond the scope of this question.

**Edit**

After the recent change in your code, you now have a problem drawing the strings in your paint method.  The issue is you are not saving the string returned by JOptionPane.showInputDialog anywhere.  It is being assigned to a local-scope variable called `text` and then just discarded.  (Note this is NOT the class-level variable `text` because you are declaring a new local variable by giving it the type again; i.e., you are using `String text = ...`.  But this isn't the actual problem.  In fact, you can get rid of the class-level `text` variable and stop drawing it whilst dragging the rectangle; it isn't needed.)

Just as you are already storing a list of shapes in a class-level variable to be redrawn every time `paint()` is called, you also need to store a list of strings to be drawn and the point at which they should be drawn.  So you'll need a new class to associate the strings with points:

```
class DrawnString {
    private final String text;
    private final Point position;
    // Insert constructor and getter methods here
}
```

You also then need a class-level list in `DrawingBoard` to store instances of these, just like your list of shapes:

```
private List<DrawnString> strings = new ArrayList<DrawnString>();
```

Now, back in your `mouseReleased` method, after getting the text from the JOptionPane, but before calling `repaint()`, you should add the string and its position to the list of DrawnStrings.

```
// Note that you need to do this BEFORE you set drawStart and drawEnd to 
// null, so move the lines where that is done to below these lines:
int stringX = Math.min(drawStart.x, drawEnd.x);
int stringY = Math.min(drawStart.y, drawEnd.y);

// now it's safe to discard these points:
drawStart = null;
drawEnd = null;

// Now save the string and its position in the list so that it can be 
// redrawn every time paint() is called:
strings.add(new DrawnString(text, new Point(stringX, stringY)));

// Now we can call repaint():
repaint();
```

Finally, in your `paint()` method, after you've drawn all your shapes (i.e., after the `for (Shape s : shapes)` loop), you should draw your strings:

```
// This is where you need to get the size of the font
FontMetrics fm = graphSettings.getFontMetrics();
int fontAscent = fm.getAscent();

for (DrawnString s : strings) {
    Point p = s.getPosition();
    // Draw with 2px padding, for example:
    graphSettings.drawString(s.getText(), p.x + 2, p.y + fontAscent + 2);
}
```

Finally, at the end of your `paint()` method, inside the `if (currentAction == 4) {...}` block, get rid of the draw string stuff there (i.e., everything after your `//Add text inside the rectangle` comment).

*Et voilà!*

Comment: thank you soo much. i've edited my code above and merge your codes, there are no errors but it's still not displaying the text inside the rectangle. Can you please check why it's not working?

Comment: Looks like you're calling `repaint()` _before_ you're getting the text value from the JOptionPane.

Comment: I've changed the code again. i've put the repaint() after the JOptionPane but still nothing, infact the "text" is not being recognised. I've tried everything. Please do your best?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  public class MyCanvas extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    Color rectColor;
    Color textColor;
    Font textFont;
    String text;

    {
        rectColor = new Color(0x0060FF);
        textColor = new Color(0x404000);
        textFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
        text = "Hello, World!";
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();
        final double size = Math.sqrt(width * height);

        //setup
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //rectangle
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        int s = (int) (size * (1 / 10d));
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width, height, s, s);

        //text
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        Font textFont = this.textFont.deriveFont((float) size * (1 / 12f));
        g.setFont(textFont);
        FontMetrics textMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        g.drawString(text, (width - textMetrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (textMetrics.getAscent() + (height - (textMetrics.getAscent() + textMetrics.getDescent())) / 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to merge your codes with mine but am having one single error on the textfont. Can you please check my code above? I've reposted it.

Comment: The line `Font textFont = this.textFont.deriveFont((float) size * (1 / 12f));` hides the backing field and auto-sizes the font for drawing. Be sure to not create the font object every time the control gets painted, as it usually takes some time to get initialised.

Comment: where should i put it instead?Can you please just adjust this for me?

Comment: Add following field to `Lesson49_1.DrawingBoard`:
`Font textFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);`

Comment: Can you please advice me on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834766/how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-of-shapes-into-partitions-lists-in-java-just-advic  Please advice? am really stuck on this?

Comment: i've put  `Font textFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);`  inside DrawingBoard() as you said. Their is now no error but it is still now working. What can you suggest?

Comment: From the code above I see you put parts of my code to `Lesson49_1` and not to  `Lesson49_1.DrawingBoard` (the nested class!) as said. Sorry to write that, but your code is a pain in my eyes, I listed you a few tips to improve your code: [link](http://pastebin.com/MxVX7HV8)

Comment: In fact i did edited the codes but did not put in into the snippet above. Please see the modified above code. You will see i did put in inside DrawingBoard() the text appears when i click on the screen and when am about to draw the rectangle then when the mouse is released it immediately disappear.

Comment: You still have this in `Lesson49_1`:  

`Font textFont;
    String text;
    Color textColor;
    {
        
        textColor = new Color(0x404000);
        
       text = "Hello, World!";
        
    }`